# leafletProxy can't find reactive data

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I apologise if I'm making some type of simple mistake here, but I haven't used Shiny much and I can't get the map I'm making with leaflet to update. The data I'm using can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobertMyles/Various_R-Scripts/master/data/carnaval.csv).

The idea is that the user chooses a date, then a region, and then clicks the name of a carnival parade using the radio buttons. After doing this, the map updates with the route of the parade and a table underneath with more details. The table works perfectly, as does the map without `leafletProxy()`. When I include the leafletProxy code block, it gives me the following error:

```
message = "argument \"data\" is missing, with no default",
```

When I debug this, I can see the data object (`test2`) and it is a dataframe like I would expect, and doesn't have NA, as was shown to be a problem in some other SO questions on this topic. (Like I say, it works fine as a table).

The code I'm using is (with the problematic part commented out):

```
#library(shiny); library(tidyverse); library(leaflet)
carnaval <- read_csv("carnaval.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(#theme = "main.min.css", # not important here
  titlePanel("Cadê o meu bloco?"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateInput("day", "Escolha a data:", min = min(carnaval$Data),
                max = max(carnaval$Data),
                value = Sys.time(), language = "pt-BR"),
      selectInput("region", "Escolha a região:",  
                  choices = carnaval$Regional),
      uiOutput("Bloco")), 
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("mapa"),
      uiOutput("detalhes")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   small_carnaval <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$day)) {
      return(NULL)
     }
    if (is.null(input$region)) {
     return(NULL)
    }
    test <- carnaval %>% filter(Data == input$day, 
                    Regional == input$region) %>% 
      select(Bloco = `Nome do bloco`, Concentração, etapa, rota, lon, lat)
    return(test)
   })

  output$Bloco <- renderUI({  
    radioButtons(inputId = "blocos", label = "Qual bloco?", 
                 choices = unique(small_carnaval()$Bloco),
                 selected = small_carnaval()$Bloco[1])
  })

  smaller_carnaval <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$blocos)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    test2 <- small_carnaval() %>% filter(Bloco %in% input$blocos) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(rota))
    return(test2)
  })

  output$detalhes <- renderUI({
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    smaller_carnaval()
  }))

  output$mapa <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = carnaval) %>%
      addTiles() %>% 
      fitBounds(lng1 = -46.743221, lat1 = -23.635246,
                lng2 = -46.463757, lat2 = -23.472222)
  })


  # observe({
  # 
  #   leafletProxy("mapa", data = small_carnaval()) %>%
  #     clearShapes() %>%
  #     clearPopups() %>%
  #     clearMarkers() %>%
  #     addMarkers(data = small_carnaval(),
  #                popup = ~paste(Bloco, etapa, sep = "\n"),
  #                lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat) %>% 
  #     fitBounds(lng1 = ~min(lon, na.rm = T), lat1 = ~min(lat, na.rm = T),
  #               lng2 = ~max(lon, na.rm = T), lat2 = ~max(lat, na.rm = T)) %>%
  #     setView(lng = ~lon,lat = ~lat, zoom = 10) %>%
  #     addPolylines(data = small_carnaval(),
  #                  lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat)
  # })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You do not need to reference data again in `addMarkers` or `addPolylines` because you've already defined it in `leafletProxy`.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, even without doing that, it doesn't work!